# lambda@edge fails when rewritten uri contains space

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

We have a lambda@edge function which takes an "obfustated" uri path and rewrites it to the correct path before the request is forwarded to s3. Whenever the s3 object contains a space, the request fails with a 502 and we can see this in the cloudfront error log:

```
ERROR Validation error: Lambda function result validation failed, the specified URI is in an invalid format, invalid character : '%20' in uri.
```

From the lambda@edge logs we can verify that the returned uri is perfectly fine, it will return something like this:
`/v2/9me/j8dk/4950/hello 2-e266dc1d-277c-4b1e-b1fd-8afbf1c14201.json`

uris containing other "special" characters seem completely fine and don't cause the cloudfront error, such as:
`/v2/9me/7zgg/4952/hello(copy)-1f77bbd0-17b8-421a-b09d-2681396e083f.json`

So I guess my question is: does cloudfront not support paths with spaces in it?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: I'm afraid not :-(